# Vakil 5.5.D: Show that Supp $m$ is the closure of those associated points of $M$ where $m$ has nonzero germ

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Here $A$ is a noetherian ring and $M$ is a finitely generated $A$-module, and $m\in M$. I'm trying to solve this by assuming

> (A) The associated primes/points of $M$ are precisely the generic points
> of irreducible components of the support of some element of $M$ (on Spec
> $A$).

I wrote down my proof but since I'm new to this topic, I'm not confident. So I really appreciate if anyone can take a quick look to verify:

Let $S={\{p\in \text{Supp}\ m \mid p \text{ is an associated point of }M\}}$, and we need to show that
\begin{align*}
    \overline{S} = \text{Supp}\ m.
\end{align*}
Since $S \subset\text{Supp}\ m$ and Supp $m$ is closed, we have
\begin{align*}
    \overline{S}\subset \text{Supp}\ m.
\end{align*}
For the other direction,
note that Spec $A$ is noetherian, so Supp $m$ as a closed subset, is the finite union of its irreducible components
\begin{align*}
    \text{Supp}\ m = \cup_{i=1}^r X_i.
\end{align*}

Each irreducible component $X_i$ has a generic point $p_i$, that is
\begin{align*}
    X_i = \overline{\{p_i\}}.
\end{align*}
By (A) these generic points are all associated points of $M$, so $p_i\in S$, it follows that
\begin{align*}
    \text{Supp}\ m = \cup_{i=1}^r \overline{\{p_i\}} = \overline{\cup_{i=1}^r\{p_i\}} \subset \overline{S}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Thanks for your time.

Comment: $S=\operatorname{Supp}(m) \cap \operatorname{Ass}(M)$ where $\operatorname{Ass}(M)$ only means the associated points of $M$ as in $\textbf{(A)}$. If $\mathfrak q \subset \operatorname{Supp}(m)$, then $\mathfrak q \in V(\mathfrak p)$ for some $\mathfrak p \in S$ since the elements of $S$ are the generic points of the irreducible components of $\operatorname{Supp}(m)$ and irreducible components cover the space. So, $\mathfrak q \in V(\mathfrak p) \subset \overline S$. So, $\operatorname{Supp}(m) \subset \overline S$.